# Problem of characteristic and minimal polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

Let $A$ be a non-diagonal $2\times 2$ matrix with complex entries such that $A=A^{-1}.$ Write down its characteristic and minimal polynomials.

### Solution

$A=A^{-1}\implies A^2=I\implies Ch_A(x)=x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$

Since Characteristic polynomial and Minimal polynomial have the same roots so,$Mp_A(x)=x^2-1$

The answer in answer key is same as I computed,but I'm getting vibes that something is wrong during transition from $2^{nd}$ step to $3^{rd}$ step.

Please give suggestions about my solution...

Thank You!!

Comment: Ask yourself: is it important or not that $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix? What about a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ such that $A=A^{-1}$?

Comment: @AndreaMori:If $A$ is a matrix of order $3\times 3,$ then the degree of $Ch_A(x)$ would be 3.Means transition from $2^{nd}$ to $3^{rd}$ is illegitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you've written down is incorrect, and you can guess that this has to be the case, because you didn't make use of the fact that $A$ is a non-diagonal matrix. Another way to see your proof is incorrect is by your comment: in your proof you didn't use the fact that $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix (but in your comment you correctly pointed out that it is the second to third implication which is erroneous becase the characteristic polynomial for a $3 \times 3$ matrix would have to be cubic).

Now, the correct approach is the following:

- Since $A = A^{-1}$, it follows that $A^2 = I$.
- Since $A^2 = I$, this means the polynomial $\alpha(x) = x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ is such that $\alpha(A) = 0$. In other words, $\alpha(x)$ is an annihilating polynomial for the matrix $A$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial $\mu_A(x)$ has to divide the annihilating polynomial $\alpha(x)$.
- From the above, we can deduce that there are $3$ possibilities for the minimal polynomial: either $\mu_A(x) = x-1$, or $\mu_A(x) = x+1$ or $\mu_A(x) = x^2 - 1$. However, the minimal polynomial has to be $x^2-1$, because if it was $x \pm 1$, then the matrix $A$ would satisfy $A \pm I = 0$, and hence $A = \pm I$. But this is a diagonal matrix, and hence would contradict the assumption that $A$ is a non-diagonal matrix. Therefore, the minimal polynomial is $\mu_A(x) = x^2-1$.
- Lastly, we know that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial (Cayley-Hamilton theorem), so the characteristic polynomial can be written as
  \begin{align}
  C_A(x) &= \phi(x) \cdot \mu_A(x)
  \end{align}
  for some polynomial $\phi(x)$. But now, we make use of the fact that $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. This means $C_A(x)$ has to be a degree 2 polynomial. But notice also that $\mu_A(x) = x^2 - 1$ is already degree 2. Therefore, $\phi(x)$ must be a constant, and in fact it is equal to $1$, because the leading coefficient of the characteristic polynomial of a $2 \times 2$ matrix is $1$.

This entire argument shows that
\begin{align}
\mu_A(x) = C_A(x) = x^2 -1.
\end{align}

Comment: :Since $C_A(x)$ and $\mu_A(x)$ have the same zeroes.So, does $\mu_A(x)=x+1$ is even possible,as at $x=1$ $C_A(x)$ is zero but $\mu_A(1)\neq 0?$

Comment: @Anwar sorry but I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: :If somehow $\mu_A(x)=x+1,$then $\mu_A(1)=2\neq 0$,but $C_A(x)=x^2-1\implies C_A(1)=0.$It means $1$ is a root of characteristic polynomial but not of minimal polynomial,which is against the law( characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial have the same zeros.)

Comment: but how do you know $C_A(x) = x^2 - 1$? (because I prove this after excluding the cases $\mu_A(x) = x \pm 1$)

Comment: :Let's make diagonalizability of $A$ legal.then what?

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that your argument is circular. I first proved that $\mu_A(x) = x^2 - 1$, and then used this to prove that $C_A(x) = x^2 - 1$. What you are suggesting is to use the fact that $C_A(x) = x^2 - 1$ to prove that $\mu_A(x) = x^2 - 1$. If you have an independent proof of this, then fine, but you're quoting my answer to justify this... which is circular reasoning.

Comment: Then, we have $3$ different cases. Case $1$ is $\mu_A(x) = x+1$. In this case, since $C_A(x)$ has to be a monic, degree $2$ polynomial with same roots as $\mu_A(x)$, it follows that $C_A(x) = (x+1)^2$. Case $2$ is $\mu_A(x) = x-1$. By similar reasoning, in this case, $C_A(x) = (x-1)^2$. Case $3$ is $\mu_A(x) = x^2 - 1$. Again, since $C_A(x)$ has to be monic, degree $2$ and have same roots, it follows $C_A(x) = x^2 - 1$.

Comment: The purpose of the non-diagonalizability assumption is to rule out case $1$ and case $2$, so we go directly to case $3$. But in general, all $3$ possibilities are allowed.

Comment: :Thanks a lot!!ActuallyI used to first compute characteristic polynomial ,then proceed towards minimal polynomial by reducing the powers of factors...